# Memory usage isn't decreasing when using free?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

Somehow this call to `free()` is not working. I ran this application on Windows and followed the memory using in Task Manager, but saw no reduction in memory usage after the call to `free()`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    int *ptr;

    ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    for (i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = 0;
    }

    free(ptr); // After this call, the program memory usage doesn't decrease

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks jaredpar,
@all
so, my syntax is absolutely correct?

Comment: yes..you are releasing the memory properly.

Comment: This is C++, not C. Perhaps a retag is justified?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typical C implementations do not return free:d memory to the operating system. It is available for use by the same program, but not to others.

Comment: calvin: Yes, there is nothing wrong with your program. It's just that the C run-time keeps the memory in the process.

Comment: (Well, there is one thing: You include iostream, but then use stdio. But that doesn't matter for the memory usage.)

Answer (score 2):

You can not assume that just after doing the `free` the memory will be returned back to OS. Generally the CRT implementation have some optimization because of which they may not return this memory immediately. This allows the CRT to allocate the subsequent memory allocation requests in a faster way.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Task manager will show the memory "borrowed" by libc from the system. But not all mallocs will go through libc to the operating system and similarly not all free will free the system memory.

Usually, libc will allocate memory in larger chunks to supply for several malloc calls.