# sidekiq memory usage reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have Rails app which uses Sidekiq for background process. To deploy this application I use capistrano, ubuntu server and apache passenger. To start and restart Sidekiq I use capistrano-sidekiq gem. 
My problem is - when Sidekiq is running, amount of memory (RAM) used by Sidekiq is growing up. And when Sidekiq finished all processes (workers) it keeps holding a large amount of RAM and not reseting it.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ubuntu    2035 67.6 45.4 3630724 1838232 ?     Sl   10:03 133:59 sidekiq 3.5.0 my_app [0 of 25 busy]
```

How to make Sidekiq to reset used memory after workers finished their work?

Comment: Looks like you are using some additional middlewares, that are creating redis keys without expiration date.

Comment: I tried `redis-cli flushall` but it did not change amount of memory hold by Sidekiq

Comment: used_memory_peak_human or used_memory_human?

Comment: Check by redis-cli info

Comment: Read more on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698911/why-does-the-redis-memory-usage-not-reduce-when-del-half-of-keys

Comment: `used_memory_peak_human:39.03M`

Comment: `used_memory_human:755.74K`

Comment: You have a leakage in your worker.

Comment: How can you see that?

Comment: Worker were running on this project, and not cleaned up. I cannot see, but I can imagine you've not cleared something like files, AR records or anything like that.

Comment: How to clean up workers? Or how to make sure they all cleaned up? Or how to check if I have any non cleaned workers? Is any command there like this `Sidekiq.please.clean.all.workers.and.empty.my.memory` ? Sorry for asking so many questions but could not find any info about that. And thank you for your help!

Comment: The root issue in your worker code, not sidekiq. You have to check why worker code is leaking. This is more deeper topic not for offtopic here.

Comment: Ok! At the moment Sidekiq holds 3GB of RAM memory after worker finished its job. So how to check what is in those 3GB of data and which worker produced so much data hold?

Comment: Create another question or just use google with keywords "debug memory leaks in ruby". It's complex topic.

Answer (score 12):

Sidekiq uses thread to execute jobs.
And threads share the same memory as the parent process.
So if one job uses a lot of memory the Sidekiq process memory usage will grow up and won't be released by Ruby.

Resque uses another technique it executes every jobs in another process therefore when the job is done, the job's process exits and the memory is released.

One way to prevent your Sidekiq process from using too much memory is to use Resque's forking method.

You could have your job main method executed in another process and wait until that new process exits

ex:

```
class Job
  include Process

  def perform
    pid = fork do
      # your code
    end
    waitpid(pid)
  end
end
```