# How can I measure process's memory usage

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, ps

I measure process's memory to use following command

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | head -n 3
```

Then process's memory is increased.
But I use free command don't increase computer's total memory usage.
some people use ps command with size keyword but other people use ps command with rss & vsz keywords.

How can I measure process's actual memory usage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem usage memory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994543/problem-usage-memory-in-c)

Comment: @KenY-N I use shared_ptr, is this same mechanism?  don't return memory block to OS?

Comment: Yes, the underlying implementation is often just `free()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061458/1270789) says there is a [`malloc_trim()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) that will try to return memory back to the OS, but I've never tried it out.