# Why the memory usage doesn't decrease after I freeing the data I alloced?

Tags: c, memory, free

I created a linked list with 1,000,000 items which took 16M memory. Then I removed and freed half of them. I thought that the memory usage would decrease, but it didn't.

Why was that?

I'm checking the Memory usage via Activity Monitor On Mac OS X 10.8.2.

In case you want to check my code, [here it is](https://gist.github.com/4124702).

Comment: the OS can wait before making available released memory pages, because he has better things to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory usage isn't decreasing when using free?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556014/memory-usage-isnt-decreasing-when-using-free)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, `free` doesn't release memory back to the OS. It's still allocated to the process, so the OS reports it as allocated. From the POV of your program, it's available to satisfy an new allocations you make.

Be aware that since you freed every other node, your memory is almost certainly now very fragmented. This free memory is in small chunks with allocated memory in between them, so can only be used to satisfy small allocations. If you make a larger allocation, the process will go to the OS for more memory.

Since the process gets memory from the OS one page at a time, even if it wanted to it *can't* release such fragmented memory back to the OS. You're using part of every page.