# vector reallocation C++

Tags: c++, stl

I was working with memory optimization while loading data in Vectors . I want to know what happens  with the memory used by Vector when  vector reallocates . I mean is it freed by Vector or not ?

thnaks in advance .

Comment: std::vector doesn't leave old unused memory around as a memory leak, if that is what you are asking. However, this applies, in C++ as well as in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556014/memory-usage-isnt-decreasing-when-using-free/1556024#1556024

Comment: I don't think the standard guarantees anything, but, in general, yes, when you exceed the current capacity, the vector will allocate a bigger, contiguous block of memory and free the old block.

Comment: thanks for ur input Brian Bi and Thomas Padron-McCarthy, I have stored 12 table in vectors it took 83.8 MB RAM but when I used vector.reserve() it took 37.8MB RAM which is close to the actual size . one line vector.reserve(1000000) making  this difference that is why I want to know this .

Comment: @VirendraBisht: If you add one item at a time, as with push_back, the memory area that the std::vector uses for its contents is grown dynamically as needed. A container such as std::vector (typically) doesn't grow one place at a time, but instead allocates some extra, for example doubling or quadrupling the reserved memory space when it needs to grow. A million push_backs without reserve is therefore likely to end up with quite a lot of unused, empty space.

Comment: ok Thomas Padron-McCarthy thanks if this is the case . then I will use reserve() function to stop this behavior as most of  my table contain 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that if you measure memory usage based on "top" or "Task Manager", the memory "freed" is not necessarily actually "made to go away". Most modern heap managers don't free the memory all the way down to the OS level, since the expectation is that memory allocated once will be needed again. Only once the amount freed reaches a certain limit (of a contiguous range, so if there are small "islands" of still used memory in the sea of freed memory, it can't be freed as one block and will most likely stay with your application "forever").

There is nothing much you can do about this, just live with it. If you know beforehand how much memory you need, use `reserve()` to reserve it. If you don't, let it grow by itself. The memory is freed, it's just not given back to the actual OS as "free memory", it sits in the heap of your application. If there is low memory in the overall system, the memory that isn't used will be swapped out and other, more useful things will be loaded into memory in its place, so it's not "occupied and can never be used for anything else". (Of course, if you have little islands of used memory that gets accessed every now and again, then it's likely that the memory can't be reused).

Answer (score 3):

For example, this is vector resize implementation in gcc 4.8.2:

```
  void resize(size_type __new_size)
  {
    if (__new_size > size())
      _M_default_append(__new_size - size());
    else if (__new_size < size())
      _M_erase_at_end(this->_M_impl._M_start + __new_size);
  }
```

So if new size is larger than the current vector size, `_M_default_append` is called:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
void vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(size_type __n)
{
  if (__n != 0)
    {
      if (size_type(this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage 
                   - this->_M_impl._M_finish) >= __n)
        {
          std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                                           __n, _M_get_Tp_allocator());
          this->_M_impl._M_finish += __n;
        }
      else // if new size is larger, execution flow goes here
        {
          //get size of a new memory block allocated for internal storage
          const size_type __len =
            _M_check_len(__n, "vector::_M_default_append");
          const size_type __old_size = this->size();
          //allocate new memory block
          pointer __new_start(this->_M_allocate(__len)); 
          pointer __new_finish(__new_start);
          __try
            {
              //move existing elements to a new memory if stored objects are movable
              //or just copy them
              __new_finish
                = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
                (this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                 __new_start, _M_get_Tp_allocator());
              //create new elements at the end of the storage
              std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(__new_finish, __n,
                                               _M_get_Tp_allocator());
              __new_finish += __n;
            }
          __catch(...)
            {
              // if exception was thrown while coping, destroy elements in new storage
              // and throw exception again
              std::_Destroy(__new_start, __new_finish,
                            _M_get_Tp_allocator());
              // deallocate new memory
              _M_deallocate(__new_start, __len);
              __throw_exception_again;
            }
          // call destructors of the elements in the old storage
          std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                        _M_get_Tp_allocator());
          // deallocate memory used for the old storage
          // _M_deallocate here checks if _M_start is not null and 
          // calls allocator's deallocate method
          _M_deallocate(this->_M_impl._M_start,
                        this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage
                        - this->_M_impl._M_start);
          // set new storage to this vector object
          this->_M_impl._M_start = __new_start;
          this->_M_impl._M_finish = __new_finish;
          this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = __new_start + __len;
        }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, vector uses allocator's `deallocate` method to remove old storage. If this is the default std::allocator, it uses `new` and `delete` operators internally. This operators usually call `malloc`/`free` methods. Some malloc implementation have tools to profile heap and to detect memory bugs, also some have options to disable memory caching in internal arenas, so you can make it return memory to OS when `free` is called. See [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/) and [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to comment due to less reputation, but you might find this helpful:

[c++ Vector, what happens whenever it expands/reallocate on stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299951/c-vector-what-happens-whenever-it-expands-reallocate-on-stack)

Comment: The idea is that you gain enough reputation by writing good answers and/or questions, not that you add comments as answers.

Comment: @juanchopanza I completely agree! But that way I want to contribute but actually not allowed to; which doesn't sound good enough! Now that I have the permission to comment, I will follow the same. It should be such that if someone has the minimum threshold reputation on any of the partner sites, he should be allowed to perform that action on all the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Failing to free memory that it was no longer using would be a fairly obvious bug in an implementation of `std::vector`. Of course, bugs do happen, so it's barely possible you *could* find such an implementation problem, but you'd normally expect `vector` to be fairly well tested so finding such a thing seems fairly unlikely (and if you did, it would probably be something that happened only under relatively obscure circumstances).

Of course, `vector` uses an `Allocator` argument (which defaults to `std::allocator<T>`) to do the actual allocation and freeing of memory (among other things). As such, a bug in the allocator class could lead to memory not being freed as intended either. Assuming you use `std::allocator<T>`, I'd be fairly surprised to see this happen, but if (for example) you're using somebody else's allocator class, problems could be quite a bit more likely (the allocator class' interface isn't immediately obvious, and good documentation on it isn't particularly common).

For what it's worth, in most (recent) implementations I've seen, `vector` expands by a factor 1.5 when it runs out of space. If the factor is smaller than the golden mean (~1.6) and the previous allocations are contiguous with each other, they'll (eventually) add up to a chunk that can satisfy a later requirement. If the factor is larger than the golden mean, they never will.

Comment: If std::allocator uses a similar OS interface as malloc(), then it doesn't always return memory to the operating system on every delete (or free). It will reuse an "unfreed" block of memory if it's large enough to handle a later allocation.