# Memory not freeing when using free BUT continues to increase when using malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, sdl-2, free

I've been trying to find information on this website about this, but the posts I've found have been a bit vague.

The program below uses SDL2 and SDL_image to display a spaceship. When the spacebar is pressed, it shoots a png out and the image moves to the right. Everything on screen is an object struct (stored in a linked list), and whenever the create_ent function is called, memory is allocated for the new object and it is displayed on screen. The move_ent function moves all objects on screen according to their xvector and yvector attributes. However, it also runs a check for whether or not the object is on screen. When the object is not on screen, it is SUPPOSED to free the object and perform the necessary (linked list) procedure for freeing the objects.

I've been using task manager as my memory usage analysis tool, and I've found that whenever the move_ents function is run, the memory is not freed. At least that is what Task Manager is telling me. I've seen in some posts that THE MEMORY IS KEPT FOR THE CURRENT PROGRAM AND IS NOT RELEASED TO THE OS ([Memory usage isn't decreasing when using free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556014/memory-usage-isnt-decreasing-when-using-free)). I'm not completely sure why that is, but my memory usage is still going up every time it runs create_ent. If this is true, should I be using realloc instead?

Some PARTS of my code are below. I've included the move_ents and create_ent function definitions, their uses in main, as well as the object struct definition.

I'd also like to point out that Visual Studio is not giving me any errors.

Is this some weird thing with Task Manager? Or is there something wrong with my freeing of the memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 1280
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 720
#define TARGET_FPS 60

struct object {

    SDL_Surface* surface;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    SDL_Point center;
    int is_ship;
    int inside;
    long float x;
    long float y;
    float w;
    float h;
    long float xvector;
    long float yvector;
    long float mass;
    long float forcex;
    long float forcey;
    float rot_speed;
    double angle;
    struct object* next;

};

void create_ent(SDL_Renderer* renderer, struct object* p, char* img_path, long float x, long float y, float w, float h, long float xvector, long float yvector, long float mass, double angle, int ship) {

    struct object* new = malloc(sizeof(struct object));

    while (p->next != NULL)
        p = p->next;

    p->next = new;

    new->surface = IMG_Load(img_path);
    if (!(new->surface))
        printf("Dammit! An image wasn't found.");

    new->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, new->surface);

    new->x = x;
    new->y = y;
    new->w = w;
    new->h = h;
    new->xvector = xvector;
    new->yvector = yvector;
    new->mass = mass;
    new->forcex = 0;
    new->forcey = 0;
    new->inside = 1;
    new->angle = angle;
    new->center = (SDL_Point){ w / 2, h / 2 };
    new->is_ship = ship;
    new->next = NULL;

}

void move_ents(struct object* p) {

    struct object* temp;

    while (p->next != NULL) {

        if ((p->next)->inside == 0) {
            if ((p->next)->next == NULL) {
                free(p->next);
                p->next = NULL;
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp = (p->next)->next;
                free(p->next);
                p->next = temp;
            }
        }

        p = p->next;

        if (!(p->is_ship))
            if ((p->x > WINDOW_WIDTH + p->w / 2) || (p->y > WINDOW_HEIGHT + p->h / 2) || (p->x < 0 - p->w / 2) || (p->y < 0 - p->h / 2)) {
                p->inside = 0;
                printf("object outside of window");
            }

        p->xvector += (p->forcex / p->mass);
        p->yvector += (p->forcey / p->mass);
        p->x += p->xvector;
        p->y += p->yvector;

    }

}
 

int main(void) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {

            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
                break;

            case SDL_KEYUP:

                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    create_ent(renderer, head, "allmine/Laser/laser.png", ship -> x + 10, ship -> y + 10, 5, 25, 10, 0, 1, ship -> angle, 0);
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    rightpressed = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    leftpressed = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    uppressed = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:

                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    rightpressed = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    leftpressed = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    uppressed = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        if (rightpressed)
            ship->angle += 5;
        else if (leftpressed)
            ship->angle -= 5;



        draw_ents(renderer, head);
        apply_forces(head, 10000);
        move_ents(head);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        // Tickrate
        frameStart = SDL_GetTicks();
        frameTime = SDL_GetTicks() - frameStart;
        if (frameTime < 1000 / TARGET_FPS)
            SDL_Delay((1000 / TARGET_FPS) - frameTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a list of anything, I suggest you separate the list and the nodes from the objects in it. Then you can create a separate set of functions to handle only the list parts, which can easily be tested and debugged in separation from the main program.

Comment: I also recommend you use pencil and paper to figure out all list operations first, using labeled boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links. Erase and redraw the arrows to make it work. When you then write the code, and there's a problem, again draw your lists while debugging and compare it to your original drawings. *Furthermore* to make things simpler, at least keep track of the tail of the list, which will make it *much* easier to append new nodes at the end. Possible also use double-linked nodes to make it easier to go back and forth.

Comment: `free()` does not return that memory block to the OS because it is nearly always somewhere in the middle of your program's address space, where it would not be accessible to other programs.  It would need to "scoot over" a bunch of your existing allocated memory to fill that gap, which is almost never worth the performance penalty.

Comment: `malloc()` libraries generally ask for a chunk of memory from the OS, then parcel it out each time it's called. `free()` marks the memory in the chunk as available for another `malloc()` if it's small enough to use the memory that was freed, otherwise if finds a chunk big enough. Free chunks can be merged when adjacent, but heap memory can be fragmented when they're not, unusably small free memory mixed in used memory. Either way, `malloc()` libraries still usually don't return the memory to the OS, assuming you're going to `malloc()` some more. `malloc_trim()` will, but is not standard.

Comment: @JohnBayko Interesting. That was very informative. Does that mean that Task Manager's behavior (as described in my post) is normal and I shouldn't worry about what it's displaying? Better yet, do know of any memory usage analysis tools for Windows?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I completely agree with you. That would make things much simpler. This is the reason that I chose to use a linked list with structs. I don't have a limit on the number of things I can put on the screen, and the list is split into nice little packages that I can manipulate. But you're right. It's difficult to tell if it's a problem with the looping or with the struct. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The Windows Task Manager offers several different memory metrics, including working set, active private working set, private working set, and commit size.  There are other, too.  Which one are you tracking?  The OS is the ultimate decider of how large a process's working set can grow.  If there's lots of memory pressure systemwide, the OS may trim your process's working set aggressively.  If there's plenty of RAM, it might not bother to reclaim pages from the working set even if the program has returned memory to the OS (which is pretty rare).